# Delete document from nested array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I've created a collection with following insert statement

```
db.test.insert({
"_id": 1,
"updatedAt": ISODate("2016-05-27T05:37:44.928Z"),
"created_at": ISODate("2016-05-13T09:41:23.000Z"),
"batchId": "BATCH-Con-0",
"size": 7,
"currentlySubscribed": 0,
"startDate": ISODate("2016-05-15T18:30:00.000Z"),
"endDate": ISODate("2016-07-08T18:30:00.000Z"),
"dailyHours": 6,
"trainer": null,
"status": "Started",
"attendance": [
    {
        "date": ISODate("2016-05-04T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "students": [
            {
                "studentId": 1,
                "entryTime": ISODate("1969-12-31T19:31:00.000Z"),
                "exitTime": ISODate("1969-12-31T19:31:00.000Z"),
                "attendanceStatus": "Present"
            },
            {
                "studentId": 2,
                "entryTime": ISODate("1969-12-31T19:31:00.000Z"),
                "exitTime": ISODate("1969-12-31T19:31:00.000Z"),
                "attendanceStatus": "Present"
            },
            {
                "studentId": ("5735a3266c1e1dc423c302cf"),
                "entryTime": ISODate("1969-12-31T19:31:00.000Z"),
                "exitTime": ISODate("1969-12-31T19:31:00.000Z"),
                "attendanceStatus": "Present"
            }


        ]
    },
    {
        "date": ISODate("2016-05-05T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "students": [
            {
                "studentId": 1,
                "entryTime": ISODate("1969-12-31T19:31:00.000Z"),
                "exitTime": ISODate("1969-12-31T19:31:00.000Z"),
                "attendanceStatus": "Present"
            },
            {
                "studentId": 2,
                "entryTime": ISODate("1969-12-31T19:31:00.000Z"),
                "exitTime": ISODate("1969-12-31T19:31:00.000Z"),
                "attendanceStatus": "Present"
            },
            {
                "studentId": 3,
                "entryTime": ISODate("1969-12-31T19:31:00.000Z"),
                "exitTime": ISODate("1969-12-31T19:31:00.000Z"),
                "attendanceStatus": "Present"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]})
```

Now I want to delete the attendance record of some of the students with this query:

```
db.test.update({},{$pull: {"attendance.$.students": {"studentId":{$in:[1,2,3]}}}},{multi:true})
```

But this gives me an error stating "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: attendance.$.students"

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), you have to have matched the array items already, something like this:

```
db.test.update(
  {"attendance.students.studentId":{$in:[1,2,3]}},
  {$pull: {"attendance.$.students": {studentId: {$in:[1,2,3]}}}},
  {multi:true}
)
```

Remember that this will only update the *first* matching item in the attendance array in each document, so you will have to run this update more than once to make it update each attendance item.

Answer (score 0):

such a complex manipulations a very hard to achieve.

Workaround to that limitation is to use forEach loop on resultSet and interate every document

```
var searchCriteria = [1, 2, 3];
db.test.find({
    "attendance.students.studentId" : {
        $in : searchCriteria
    }
}).forEach(function (myDoc) {
    var len = myDoc.attendance.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        var x = myDoc.attendance[i];
        var xLen = x.students.length;
        var newArrayWithStudents = [];

        for (var j = 0; j < xLen; j++) {
            if (searchCriteria.indexOf(x[j].studentId) < 0) {
                newArrayWithStudents.add(x[j]);
            };

        };
        myDoc.attendance[i] = newArrayWithStudents;
    };

    myDoc.save();

});
```